# text-transform: uppercase; is not working while storing the value into database

Tags: asp.net

i am using text-transform: uppercase; for my textbox. It is showing starting Capital letter for each word. But it is storing into database as we enter in textbox.  I want to store the textbox value as we see in the textbox with  style - "text-transform: uppercase;"

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Text-transform is a CSS property, it will only affect how the text displays, not how the input is posted to the server.

use ToUpper() instead server side, before inputting into the database.

Comment: Thanks paul. If i want the text as "capitalize" to store then what method can i use to convert and store.

Answer (score 0):

You are using css to transform the latter, instead of doing this you can use this code,

```
var changesCase = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(txt.Text);
```

I'm Assuming your textbox id is `txt`